# Autoload Template List Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, conditional-statements

The list of template is loaded when a tab is click but what I am trying to achieve is to preload the list of template with th
ee default tab I set , currently, it only loads the template list when a tab is click or selected

http://pastebin.com/mDxG2srG

I tried putting a condition but it doesn't seem to work

```
 if ($category['ID'] == 1 )  {

  <div class="template-signup-item theme-screenshot-wrap " data-tkey="1" id="theme-screenshot-wrap-1">
            <a href="#template" data-theme-key="<? echo $value; ?>" class="blog_template-item_selector">
                <img src="<? echo $root; ?>">
                <input type="radio" id="blog-template-radio-1" name="blog_theme" value="1" style="display: none">
            </a>                                
        </div>

}
```